# Java + Android: вопросы новичка по использованию методов

Tags: java, android

Я хочу программно добавить `TextView` и другие виджеты. Вот как я это делаю на данный момент (всё работает):

```
public void AddTextInput(View view) {

    // Указываем через ID контейнерный элемент, куда будем добавлять виджет 
    LinearLayout AddItemContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.AddItemContainer);

    // Устанавливаем разметы виджета
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams AddedItemsSizing = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    EditText TextInputA = new EditText(this); // Создаём объект EditText
    TextInputA.setLayoutParams(AddedItemsSizing); // Задаём ему размеры
    TextInputA.setHint(R.string.TextInputAValue); // Устанавливаем параметры
    AddItemContainer.addView(TextInputA); // Добавляем виджет
}
```

Этот метод добавляет только поле ввода текста, но теперь я хочу создать метод, который добавляет и другие виджеты (через вспомогательные методы). Вот мой **неправильный** код:

```
public void AddItem(int Item_ID){

// Указываем через ID контейнерный элемент, куда будем добавлять виджет 
LinearLayout AddItemContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.AddItemContainer);

// Устанавливаем разметы виджета
LinearLayout.LayoutParams AddedItemsSizing = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

switch (Item_ID){
    case 1:
        AddTextInput();
        break;
    case 2:
        AddPenInput();
        break;
    case 3:
        AddPhoto();
        break;
    case 4:
        AddVideo();
        break;
    case 5:
        AddSoundRec();
        break;
}
}

public void AddTextInput(View view) {

EditText TextInputA = new EditText(this); // Создаём объект EditText
TextInputA.setLayoutParams(AddedItemsSizing); // Задаём ему размеры
TextInputA.setHint(R.string.TextInputAValue); // Устанавливаем параметры
AddItemContainer.addView(TextInputA); // Добавляем виджет
}
```

Теперь `AddTextInput` - вспомогательный метод, который вызывается из основного `AddItem`. Настройки размера и всех виджетов будут одинаковы, потому я вынес их в основной метод.

Итак, вопросы:

- Как сделать `AddItemContainer` и `AddedItemsSizing` доступными в `AddTextInput` и других вспомогательных методах?
- В блоке Switch я неправильно вызываю вспомогательные методы. В чём именно некорректность? (пробовал также `AddTextInput(View view)` и `AddTextInput(view)`)
- Метод `AddItem` имеет аргумент - ID виджета. Правильно ли я задал вызов метода `OnClick` в XML-разметке?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По правилам данного ресурса вопрос должен содержать **одну** конкретную проблему, решение которой (в идеале) может помочь другим людям с аналогичной проблемой. В текущем виде ваш вопрос не подходит под цели данного ресурса. Рекомендую переформулировать его и разбить на несколько вопросов.

Comment: Заменил этот вопрос [на другой](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/563743/java-android-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4).

Comment: Удалять нельзя, потому что есть ответ. Но это не проблема, пускай остаётся )

Answer (score 1):

1. Передавайте размеры, как параметр метода (прим. AddTextInput(View view, float width, float height) ).
2. Я не совсем понял, зачем вы в вашем "вспомогательном методе" передаете параметр View. Пример, есть метод AddTextInput(float width, float height), то вызываться он будет так: AddTextInput(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT).
3. В разметке вы обрабатываете нажатие на сам контейнер. Если вы хотите обрабатывать нажатие на конкретный view, вам надо определять метод onClick в нем. Метод - setOnClickListener