# Java + Android: Как программно выполнить метод

Tags: java, android

Известно, что методы позволяют избежать повторения кода. Вопрос новичка: как правильно заменить повторяющийся код на одну строку с методом в Java?

Чтобы Вам не пришлось думать, какой пример привести, приведу его сам. Допустим у нас есть метод добавления поля воода:

```
// Указываем через ID контейнерный элемент, куда будем добавлять виджет 
LinearLayout AddItemContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.AddItemContainer);

public void AddTextInput(View view) {

EditText TextInputA = new EditText(this); // Создаём объект EditText
TextInputA.setHint(R.string.TextInputAValue); // Устанавливаем параметры
AddItemContainer.addView(TextInputA); // Добавляем виджет
}
```

Я могу назначить этот метод кнопке, и при нажатии на кнопку всё сработает.
Вопрос: а что, если я хочу, чтобы **этот же** метод срабатывал не только при нажатии кнопки,    но и при других условиях, например:

- Открылась активность и этот метод выполнился
- Прошло определённое количество времени и метод выполнился
- Выполнен другой метод, а этот выполнялся вслед за ним

Не надо решать каждую из этих задач в отдельности - я просто увидеть **одну** строку кода, которая добавит TextView в соответвии со всеми теми настройками, что внутри метода **AddTextInput**, т. е. выполнит этот метод.

Comment: оффтоп: прочитайте что нибудь по `java code conventions`, и чем раньше, тем лучше...тем более если новичек

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Судя по всему, вы назначили `onClick()` через XML разметку так `android:onClick="AddTextInput"`. **Никогда** так не делайте. Потому, что если вы измените что-нибудь в своем коде, или разметке, это с большой вероятностью приведет к ошибкам. Если не понятно, то просто поверьте мне наслово. Делайте вместо этого так:

   ```
   Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button); 
   button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){...});
   ```
2. В вашем методе ненужен параметр, поэтому его можно убрать:

   ```
   public void AddTextInput() {
       EditText TextInputA = new EditText(this); // Создаём объект EditText
       TextInputA.setHint(R.string.TextInputAValue); // Устанавливаем параметры
       AddItemContainer.addView(TextInputA); // Добавляем виджет
   }
   ```
3. Теперь, вызвав где угодно `AddTextInput();` вы получите то ,что хотели.
4. Обратите внимание на комментарий @ermak0ff. Соблюдайте `java code conventions`, если не хотите, чтобы у других при чтении вашего кода кровоточили глаза.

Comment: Идеальный ответ! Спасибо за ответ и рекомендации!