# Java + Android: добавление view через метод с параметрами

Tags: java, android

Этот вопрос - продолжение темы [Java + Android: Как программно выполнить метод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/563743/java-android-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4), где был пример добавления поля ввода через метод:

```
public void AddTextInput() {
    EditText TextInputA = new EditText(this); // Создаём объект EditText
    TextInputA.setHint(R.string.TextInputAValue); // Устанавливаем параметры
    AddItemContainer.addView(TextInputA); // Добавляем виджет
}
```

Теперь: как сделать то же самое, но ещё передать в метод `AddTextInput()` параметры из `OnCreate()`?

```
public void AddTextInput(){

    AddItemContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.AddItemContainer);
    AddedItemsSizing = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    EditText TextInput1 = new EditText(this);
    TextInput1.setLayoutParams(AddedItemsSizing);
    TextInput1.setHint("Введите текст:");
    AddItemContainer.addView(TextInput1);
}
```

На данный момент ID контейнера `AddItemContainer` и размеры `AddedItemsSizing` находятся внутри класса (переменные объявлены в `OnCreate()`. Я же хочу, чтобы эти переменные были инициализированы вне метода, т. к. они будут использоваться и в других методах.

Где у меня возникли проблемы:

- Если инициализировать перменные `AddItemContainer` и `AddedItemsSizing` в `OnCreate()`, то Android Studio "ругаться" не будет, но приложение - слетит при выполнении `AddTextInput()`.
- Если добавить ещё сам `AddTextInput()` внутри OnCreate, тогда студия будет ругаться на отсутствие параметров, которые, как было сказано в ответе на мой [предыдущий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/563743/java-android-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4), не нужны.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Имена переменных в Java **всегда** с маленькой буквы, если это не константы. В нынешнем виде они у вас как и классы названы, что делает ваш код почти нечитаемым.
2. Инициализируйте ваши параметры в onCreate
3. Дайте вашим методам аргумент в виде этих параметров
4. Вызывайте методы, передавая туда эти параметры.

---

```
public void addTextInput(LinearLayout.LayoutParams params) {
     ...
}
```

Вызывайте так из onCreate:

```
params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
addTextInput(params);
```

Comment: с маленькой буквы это как надо? типо так?
`int[] arrayTest = new int[10]` или так `int[] arraytest = new int[10]` ?

Comment: @KryTer_NexT, первый вариант. Только первая буква маленькая у переменных, далее каждое новое слово - с большой. Отличие от именования классов - только в том, что первая буква - маленькая